# How to read the data from web

Tags: r

I would like to import the data from http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/regression/mg
into R. This dataset contains 1,385 data points featuring 6 independent variables and 1 dependent variable. How can I import this data file into R?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are looking for `read.table`:

```
read.table("http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/regression/mg")
```

If you want to remove the column numbers and the colons from the numeric values, you can use `gsub`:

```
dat <- read.table("http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/regression/mg",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat[-1] <- lapply(dat[-1], function(x) as.numeric(gsub(".:", "", x)))
```

Comment: I first save the data as mg.txt. Then:                            w<-read.fwf("mg.txt",width=c(13,3,13,3,13,3,13,3,13,3,13,3,13))
ww<-w[,seq(1,13,by=2)]
it also can get the result. Thank all the same.